# Can I login to Facebook using Facebook iOS SDK without opening Facebook app?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

Can I login to Facebook (get access token) using Facebook iOS SDK without opening native Facebook app? - For Facebook app I already logged in, access to my application approved.

Right now:

1. I use Login with Facebook button.
2. User push the button.
3. Facebook app opening.
4. Facebook white screen with progress show.
5. Facebook app closing.
6. My app retrieve token in the applicationOpenURLWithSourceAnnotation event handler.

How can I hide opening Facebook app with white screen, because it does not has a sence!?

Comment: I don't think you can manage that, it also depends if the user has the Facebook app installed otherwise there will be just a popover screen with Facebook Login in your own app.

Comment: @Tom Spee, thanks for response. Sure, Facebook app is installed. I described the situation.

Comment: If I'm correct this will only happen once right? Just on the first login of a user. They will not have approved your Facebook App and so the screen won't be white. To get back to your main question, I've not been able to manage the way Facebook Login works on my apps.

Comment: @Tom Spee, yes, approving occures once. But for example if I logged out from my app and lose the current token, which Facebook app has. I have to login with Facebook app once again and in this case Facebook app shows white screen and then closing (approving not necessary). And how to exclude this white screen?

Comment: You're right, if you logout you get the same scree. Unfortunately I've not enough experience with Facebook Login to help you with that. Maybe you can try the [Facebook Developers](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/) page on Facebook.

Comment: @Tom Spee, thanks about the info about Facebook group, but the question is still opened...

Comment: You can't. To get the token via SSO, there needs to be a fast-app-switch to the FB app, from there, since the user has already authorized your app, no further UI is needed, so it switches back, but the app-switch is unavoidable.